# Using setScrollY for ListView, adapter's setView doesn't display proper item

Tags: android

I have a ListView which I scroll to a specific position using setScrollY. For some reason, if I use setScrollY to scroll to a coordinate that is supposed to show the 7th item, it's blank. I have more than 6 items on the list.

I put a log on the getView and it only processes the 1st 6 items.

On the screen only 6 items of the list are visible.

What needs to happen getView to process other items?

If I manually scroll the ListView, getView process the other items properly.

My code for the Activity is below:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity  {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_bride_groom_or_guest);

    lvImages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.image_list);
    lvImages.setEnabled(false);

    drawableIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_1);
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_2);
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_3);
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_4);
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_5);
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_6);
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_7);
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_8);
    drawableIds.add(R.drawable.auth_background_row_9);

    adapter = new AuthBackgroundImageAdapter(this, drawableIds);

    lvImages.setAdapter(adapter);

    int scrollY = //some number which is higher than the screen height.

    lvImages.setScrollY(scrollY);

}


}
```

Adapter

```
public class AuthBackgroundImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "AuthBackgroundImageAdapter";
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
List<Integer> drawableIds;

class Holder {
    ImageView ivBackground;
}


public AuthBackgroundImageAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> drawableIds) {
    this.drawableIds = drawableIds;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItem(Integer drawableId) {
    drawableIds.add(drawableId);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return drawableIds.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return drawableIds.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    Holder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_auth_background_image, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.ivBackground = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.auth_background_image);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }

    Integer item = (Integer) this.getItem(position);
    holder.ivBackground.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(item));

    Log.d(TAG, "getView: position " + String.valueOf(position));
    Log.d(TAG, "getView: drawable " + String.valueOf(item));

    return view;
}


}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/image_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

Comment: Can you add the xml code of the list view contined in the layout activity_choose_bride_groom_or_guest

Comment: Try making class Holder static like this: static class Holder

Comment: @dannyroa did u found any solution? i am facing almost same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `android:layout_height` parameter with `wrap_content` value:

```
      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/image_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
```